# Using if else case in Python to have a derived column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, if-statement

I have a query in my code, where am trying to use if else case to derive a value in a data frame,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
c=15
s={'yr':[2014,2014,2014,2014],'value':[10,20,20,50]}
p=pd.DataFrame(data=s)

if (p['value'])>= c:
    p['qty']=c-p['value']
else:
    p['value']
```

I am getting the error in the above code-

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Basically this should be my expected output-

```
    yr    value qty
0   2014    10  10
1   2014    20  5
2   2014    20  5
3   2014    50  35
```

How should I solve this error?

Comment: Do you mean `p['value'] - c` instead of `c - p['value']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), assuming your intended calculation is `p['value']-c` rather than `c-p['value']`:

```
p['qty'] = np.where(p['value'] >= c, p['value']-c, p['value'])
```

Result:

```
     yr  value  qty
0  2014     10   10
1  2014     20    5
2  2014     20    5
3  2014     50   35
```

Answer (score 3):

You can select certain rows with the loc statement:

```
# initialize the qty column
df['qty'] = df['value']
# adjust qty where qty is larger than c
df.loc[df['qty'] > c, 'qty'] -= c
```

Answer (score 1):

`if` expects a boolean value (True/False) but `(p['value'])>= c` is a Series, so you're getting that error. One way to get the desired output is to use `mask`:

```
p['qty'] = p['value'].mask(lambda x: x>=c, p['value']-c)
```

Another option is to use `numpy.where`:

```
import numpy as np
p['qty'] = np.where(p['value']>=c, p['value']-c, p['value'])
```

Output:

```
     yr  value  qty
0  2014     10   10
1  2014     20    5
2  2014     20    5
3  2014     50   35
```

Comment: "`if` expects a boolean value (True/False)" - this is not strictly true. `if` can accept anything that can evaluate to a boolean, and the implementors of the `Series` object have decided that evaluating a `Series` in a boolean context is ambiguous so throw an error instead of doing something the user might not expect.

Comment: @SethMMorton You're right, I should've said "truthy"

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to operate element-wise on a column, that usually requires iteration or applying a function

```
p['qty'] = p['value'].apply(lambda x: c - x if x >= c else x)
```